# Exporting an SVG from Illustrator using a class name for the color

Tags: svg, icons, fill, adobe-illustrator

I have about 200 icons built in one illustrator file. I am trying to figure out a way to set the color to be a class name, instead of a hex value, so that the class name is assigned to the object so that it can be more easily changed with CSS.

For example, this is what I am able to export so far:

```
<svg id="Iconography" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path id="Compound_Path" data-name="Compound Path" d="M19.34,14.68A1,1,0,0,1,18,16l-6-6L6,16a1,1,0,0,1-1.35-1.34L11.29,8a1,1,0,0,1,1.42,0Z" fill="#707070"/></svg>
```

But I'd like fill="#707070" to be fill="colorIconPrimary", as opening every svg after exporting and manually changing is very laborious (plus some icons may have multiple colors)

Comment: Not sure if the renaming can be done within Illustrator during export. But Illustrator (or any other Adobe app, or node.js, or python, etc, for that matter) can do any text replacing in any txt files via script. You don't need to do it manually if you can formulate the rules for the changes.

Comment: Did you get an answer? It doesn't look fine, to say the least, to ask questions and don't even provide any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

This script can replace `fill="#707070"` with `fill="colorIconPrimary"` within all svg files in the folder "d:\tmp":

```
var folder = Folder("d:/tmp");
var files = folder.getFiles("*.svg");

for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    var f = File(files[i]);
    f.open("r");
    var contents = f.read();
    f.close();
    contents = contents.replace(/fill="#707070"/g, 'fill="colorIconPrimary"')
    f.open("w");
    f.write(contents);
    f.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Still much easier than opening each file and doing it manually.

Answer (score 2):

In Illustrator, any elements which have their *fill* or *stroke* color set to RGB black (#000000) will export without any styling properties.

These elements in your SVG will therefore inherit whatever you define in your CSS when used inline

```
svg#iconography {
  fill: blue;
  stroke: red;
}
```

This approach also works with externally referenced SVG fragments too (multiple icons in one cacheable SVG file). More info can be found [here](https://twitter.com/_AntiAlias_/status/1422794300903944192?s=20)