# Can you put AI layers seperately into code

Tags: html, css, adobe-illustrator

I have an illustration in one main colour. As an example, orange. I use lighter and darker orange colours for contrast. I want to do the same with any colour via Css without recolouring the illustration in Illustrator. How can I get an AI file with the layers into the code so that I can then change only the main colour?

Comment: I believe it can be done if you export your artwork into SVG format. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68397857/exporting-an-svg-from-illustrator-using-a-class-name-for-the-color

Comment: SVG has no layers though, as far as I can tell. But I can be wrong.

Comment: Use opacity to get "lighter and darker"colours. Select Same Fill & Stroke. Change fill colour.

Comment: @YuriKhristich yes SVG worked. so the solution is to make the svg like “a kids drawing book”. you just draw the outlines, and then fill the color